# Java, Timing, Events

Tags: java, events, command-line, command

I'm a relatively new programmer and I'm using Java to build a hangman game.  My questions mainly have to do with what I will call "timing and/or events"(if you feel there is a better description please let me know).

When my application starts execution a few things happen: 1) It displays a greeting message("Welcome to Java Hangman..."), 2) it calls startgame(), one of the things that startgame() does is calls drawman(o), this display an empty gallows, 3) if you are winning(which of course you would be since the game just started), a questions is displayed for the user to try and answer(all of this code is bellow).

My questions/what I would like to do is: 1) have the greeting message "flash"(appear and disappear) every 2 seconds, WHILE the empty gallows(manZero()) is being "built" on the screen, 2) to "build" the empty gallows, either start at the "top" or "bottom" and display a different "pieces"(String) of the gallows every 2 seconds until complete, 3) once the last piece of the gallows if "built", greeting message stops "flashing" and then user is prompted with the first question.

End result: game begins, greeting message "flashes", while gallows is being "built", after last piece of gallows is added, greeting stops "flashing" and question is posed.

Described another way, output would look something like this:

```
//application begins execution 

System.out.println("Welcome to Java Hangman...");// greet flashes every two seconds

// meanwhile the gallows is being built below greet
public void manZero() 
{ 
    System.out.println("_____"); // 2 sec after that this string appears("last piece")
    System.out.println("|   |"); // 2 seconds after that this string appears
    System.out.println("|   "); // 2 seconds after that this string appears
    System.out.println("|   "); // 2 seconds later this string appears
    System.out.println("|   "); // first this string appears
```

When the "last piece" appears in the output, greeting stops flashing, the empty gallows(manZero()) is intact, and the first question is then posed to user(i.e. appears in output).

This is a multistage question and I realize Stack like things to be concise but since these questions all deal with similar issues I though it would make a good and possibly fun topic.  Additionally, since I am new to programming please provide examples with suggestions, preferably complete examples using the existing code, as it doesn't take much for me to find myself in the weeds.

Right now the game runs in command but I'm interested in adding some swing features, if you would like to help me with this or would like to see the code for the entire program please email me at reedwilliams8404@gmail.com

Thank you for your time and input, I'm interested in what you come up with.

```
/*
main, greeting, call to start
*/

public class HangmanMain 
{


    public static void main(String[] args)      
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Java Hangman...");
        HangmanGame hangmanGame = new HangmanGame(initQuestions());
        try 
        {
            hangmanGame.startGame();
        } 

/*
startGame(), call to drawman(O), pose first question
*/

public HangmanGame(List<Question> questions) 
{
    this.questions = questions;
    manDrawer = new ManDrawer();
    questionPoser = new QuestionPoser();
}
// sets/resets values 
public void startGame() throws IOException 
{
    manDrawer.drawMan(0);
    incorrectGuesses = 0;
    guesses = 6;

    // for each Question question in questions
    for(Question question : questions) 
    {
        // not winning
        if(!isWinning) 
        {
            break;
        }
        // winning
        else 
        {
            questionPoser.poseQuestion(question);
            askQuestionUntilCorrectOrOutOfGuesses(question);
            handleQuestionSuccessOrGameFailure(question);
        }
    }


/*
"builds" gallows
*/


//gets value  of field incorrectGuesses, determines corresponding method to call,
// calls corresponding method, corresponding method displays/draws hangman image 
public class ManDrawer 
{

// determines which man#() to call based on the value of incorrectGuesses 
public void drawMan(int incorrectGuesses)
{
    switch (incorrectGuesses) {
        case 0:
            manZero();
            break;
        case 1:
            manOne();
            break;
            //...

// value of incorrectGuesses is 0
public void manZero() 
{ 
    System.out.println("_____"); 
    System.out.println("|   |"); 
    System.out.println("|   "); 
    System.out.println("|   "); 
    System.out.println("|   "); 
} 

// value of incorrectGuesses is 1
public void manOne() 
{ 
    System.out.println("_____"); 
    System.out.println("|   |"); 
    System.out.println("|   o"); 
    System.out.println("|    "); 
    System.out.println("|    "); 
} 
//...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1 question(blinking Welcome to Java Hangman...) this should work fine on the system console but not in IDE console.

```
try {
   int i=0;
   while (i<10) {
      System.out.print("Welcome to Java Hangman...");
      Thread.sleep(100);
      System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
      Thread.sleep(100);
      i++;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
}
```

For the 2 part for drawing the hangman figure you can do something like this:

```
try
{
    final String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        manDrawer.drawMan(i);
        Thread.sleep(200);
        if (os.contains("Windows")) {
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
         } else {
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
         }
    }
} catch (final Exception e) {
   //  Handle any exceptions.
}
```

---

EDIT:

[Eclipse Bug #76936.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936) there are no workarounds listed.

You might have luck finding a plugin that contributes a more advanced console.

Comment: Excellent, I see \b is the backspace escape character.  So if i understand your code correctly, what we are doing is printing the greeting, sleeping via Tread, deleting it via \b, sleeping again, adding 1 to i each iteration, repeating until i holds a value of 10.

If correct

At this point would the greet be displayed in a fixed non-flashing state?  And is there a way to time the non-flashing with the completion of the gallows?

Comment: Yes indeed ! ... I didn't understand your second question so cannot help you in that !

Comment: I edited the post and articulated the question in another way.  This might help.

Comment: Thank you and I most definitely will.

Could you explain to me why the first section of code will not run in an IDE(I currently use Eclipse Luna)?

Comment: amended question.  look at end.

Comment: Sorry you should ask one question per question you cannot ask 3 in one question ! please post another question with a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more help !

Answer (score 0):

Make the thread sleep for 2 seconds.

```html
try{
Thread.sleep(2000)
}catch...
```

Comment: hey Mahesh, would you mind shooting me an email, so I can show you how I would employ your suggest.  Maybe you could tell me if I'm on the right track and help me to better understand how i'm achieving this effect.

reedwilliams8404@gmail.com